# Fetching data from another website

Tags: php

I am making a new website using PHP and I want to fetch the data from another website in which I have my profile, which contains wallpapers, logos etc.

I want to fetch the data from that website and display it on my new website in the content section.

Please give me some ideas on how to do this task in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

See e.g. the [curl extension](http://php.net/curl) or the [http wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) for retrieving the content.

See the [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom) for parsing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to make a web request to a web address and get the HTML back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send requests to the remote site and fetch the results.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the who the site is, they may have provided an API for accessing that info.  That  generally applies for larger sites like facebook and such.

Answer (score 0):

[PEAR::HTTP_Request](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/redirected)

```
// Fetches yahoo.com and displays it
require_once "HTTP/Request.php";

$req =& new HTTP_Request("http://www.yahoo.com/");
if (!PEAR::isError($req->sendRequest())) {
    echo $req->getResponseBody();
}
```