# Displaying on my website another webpage at users request.

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching data from another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174032/fetching-data-from-another-website)

I want to create a webpage, that would display another webpage on it at user's request. User enters URL and sees webpage he wants on my website. Request to another page **has to come from my server, not from user**. Otherwise I could just use iframe.

I'm willing to write it on php because I know some of it. Can anyone tell me what subjects one must know to do this ?

Comment: what does `Request to another page has to come from my server, not from user. ` exactly mean?

Comment: Till, it's not fetching some data. But displaying the whole page as it is.

Comment: The COMPLETE PHP Newbie, say (for instance) you are banned at some specific website, and you can't access it directly. So my script would access that webpage and display it for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of "PHP Proxy" for this, that means get the website contents via curl or file_get_contents(). Have a look at this here: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download
Your proxy script that may look like this:

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
echo get_data($_GET["url"]);
```

Please note that you may have to pay attention to headers for images etc. and there may also be some security flaws, but that is the basic idea.
Now you have to parse the contents of the initial website you just got and change all links from this format:

```
http://example.com/thecss.css
```

to

```
http://yoursite.com/proxy.php?url=http://example.com/thecss.css
```

Some regexes or PHP HTML parser may work here.

Comment: thank you for this answer
can you speak a little more about headings and images ?

Comment: In order to have your browser display e.g. images correctly, you need to send the right [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). You can the headers from the original file you are retrieving like [this](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-headers)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com')
```

But why not just download a php webproxy package like http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/

Comment: This will not work for all arbitrary files like CSS, the request comes from the user then, not from the server the script is running on

Comment: the project you have posted is not under active development since 2007